# Average value of fields in wordpress posts

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

All my posts has a rating of 1-5 and on my category page I want to display the average rating of all the posts of that category. So I know where the field with the value is within the post loop, but how can I get those values and calculate the average outside the post loop?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is probably to construct an array during the loop and average it at the end.

```
// Before the loop

$ratings = array();

// During the loop

$ratings[] = $post_rating;

// After the loop

$average = array_sum($ratings) / count($ratings);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess that could work but the thing is that some of my categories have more posts then are being displayed. Therefor i think i have to go into the MYSQL database and get the values from there..?

Comment: Yup. Something along the lines of `SELECT tr.term_taxonomy_id AS category_id, AVG(p.post_rating) as rating_average FROM wp_term_relationships AS tr JOIN wp_posts AS p ON tr.object_id = p.ID WHERE term_taxonomy_id = $category_id`. That won't work, because your "rating" is probably not stored in the main posts table, but something along those lines would do it.

Comment: Can someone elaborate on the above answer for a noob. Thanks.